# Refresh current page from method after submited

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay, I'm new the PHP writing, and i got stuck.

I have this code:

```
    add_shortcode( 'mycred_take', 'mycred_pro_render_take_shortcode' );
function mycred_pro_render_take_shortcode( $atts, $label = 'Give Away' ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'user_id' => '',
        'confirm' => '',
        'amount'  => '',
        'unique'  => 0,
        'ref'     => 'mycred_take',
        'entry'   => '%plural% lose',
        'ctype'   => 'mycred_default'
    ), $atts ) );

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! function_exists( 'mycred' ) ) return '';

    if ( $user_id == '' )
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Load essentials
    $user_id = absint( $user_id );
    $mycred = mycred( $ctype );

    // User is excluded = has no balance
    if ( $mycred->exclude_user( $user_id ) ) return '';

    // Unique check
    if ( $unique == 1 && $mycred->has_entry( $ref, 0, $user_id, '', $ctype ) ) return '';

    $balance = $mycred->get_users_balance( $user_id, $ctype );

    $output = '';

    // If button was pushed
    if ( isset( $_POST['mycred-take-points-token'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mycred-take-points-token'], 'mycred-deduct-points' . $ref . $ctype ) ) {

        // Deduct
        $mycred->add_creds(
            $ref,
            $user_id,
            0 - $amount,
            $entry
        );

        // Update balance
        $balance = $balance - $amount;

    }

    // Too low balance
    if ( $balance < $amount ) return '';

    return $output . '<form action=""  method="post" id="mycred-take-shortcode' . $ref . $ctype . '"><input type="hidden" name="mycred-take-points-token" value="' . wp_create_nonce( 'mycred-deduct-points' . $ref . $ctype ) . '" /><input type="submit"  class="button"  value="' . $label . '" /></form>';
}
```

It's one Wordpress shortcode. I want after the form submited and the database updated, refresh the page. Since this code is currently down and the page is not updated (if i'm refresh the page manually the database updated, and the changes is appear). I try the onSubmit="window.location.reload()", action="" codes, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Meil Helt please try to replace your code with my below code.

```
add_action("init","start_ob_start_cb");
function start_ob_start_cb()
{
     ob_start();
}

add_shortcode( 'mycred_take', 'mycred_pro_render_take_shortcode' );
function mycred_pro_render_take_shortcode( $atts, $label = 'Give Away' ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'user_id' => '',
        'confirm' => '',
        'amount'  => '',
        'unique'  => 0,
        'ref'     => 'mycred_take',
        'entry'   => '%plural% lose',
        'ctype'   => 'mycred_default'
    ), $atts ) );

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() || ! function_exists( 'mycred' ) ) return '';

    if ( $user_id == '' )
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // Load essentials
    $user_id = absint( $user_id );
    $mycred = mycred( $ctype );

    // User is excluded = has no balance
    if ( $mycred->exclude_user( $user_id ) ) return '';

    // Unique check
    if ( $unique == 1 && $mycred->has_entry( $ref, 0, $user_id, '', $ctype ) ) return '';

    $balance = $mycred->get_users_balance( $user_id, $ctype );

    $output = '';

    // If button was pushed
    if ( isset( $_POST['mycred-take-points-token'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['mycred-take-points-token'], 'mycred-deduct-points' . $ref . $ctype ) ) {

        // Deduct
        $mycred->add_creds(
            $ref,
            $user_id,
            0 - $amount,
            $entry
        );

        // Update balance
        $balance = $balance - $amount;
wp_redirect(get_permalink()); die();
    }

    // Too low balance
    if ( $balance < $amount ) return '';

    return $output . '<form action=""  method="post" id="mycred-take-shortcode' . $ref . $ctype . '"><input type="hidden" name="mycred-take-points-token" value="' . wp_create_nonce( 'mycred-deduct-points' . $ref . $ctype ) . '" /><input type="submit"  class="button"  value="' . $label . '" /></form>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it before return

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Comment: If I do this, as soon as the shortcode appears, the page is reload. And not the after clicked the form button.